# Remove character in a specific column using sub comand and the pipe operator approach in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyr

I would like to use the `sub` command to remove this `X` leaving only the numbers.

I would like to use the `%>%` pipe operator approach, as it avoids creating intermediate data.frames and makes the code much cleaner.

I tried using something like this, but to no avail:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(20,3,2),x2=c(19,4,2), x3=c(20,3,2))%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=x1:x3, names_to = "name1", values_to = "value1")%>%
  sub('X','','name1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `dplyr::mutate` to apply a function like `sub` on a column of your data set, creating new columns or replace the existing ones.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(x1=c(20,3,2),x2=c(19,4,2), x3=c(20,3,2))%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=x1:x3, names_to = "name1", values_to = "value1") %>%
  mutate(name1 = sub('[^0-9]', '', name1))


# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name1 value1
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 1         20
2 2         19
3 3         20
4 1          3
5 2          4
6 3          3
7 1          2
8 2          2
9 3          2
```

Comment: I changed `'^[0-9]'` for `'x'` in `mutate(name1 = sub('x', '', name1))` and worked

Comment: Yes it works where there is only letter `x` but `[^0-9]`  is more generalizable for any other non-numeric character. Thought this way the solution is more robust.